# Wiring an RCD breaker in a subpanel

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel

According to my electrical project, I am supposed to add a currently missing RCD to breakers 2, 3 and 4 (but not 1).
Two questions:

1. any idea why is the breaker would not need to be added to the 3-phase breaker powering the stove? To me, it feels like in this I would be missing out on the benefits of the RCD for that line?
2. how would I go about wiring this to a RCD breaker that I bought?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: For our North American readers.  Firstly RCD == GFGI.  Secondly, this is a fairly modern European system.  The incoming utility power is three phase + neutral.  230V phase to neutral, 415V phase to phase.  Wiring colours are: brown, black, and grey for phase wires, blue for the neutral wire, and green+yellow for the ground wire.  (Typical single phase cable uses brown for phase, and the mnemonic is "it knocks the shit out of you".)

Comment: What do the instructions say.  Most stuff like this come with instructions on how to install/wire.

Answer (score 3):

RCDs are either stand-alone devices (which take room/spaces in your electrical panel) or they are RCBOs, which are a combination circuit breaker + RCD.

Anything downline of an RCD or RCBO (i.e. that loses power when that device is tripped with the TEST button) is protected by that RCD or RCBO.

If there is a feed breaker supplying this subpanel, the RCBO could actually be *there, in that breaker*.  It would then protect all loads in this subpanel, and no additional RCDs would be required.

However, the more things an RCD/RCBO protects, the more it is at risk for nuisance trips from the cumulative ordinary leakage or capacitive coupling that is unavoidable.  The North American practice is to protect only one circuit at a time, but use a more sensitive (5mA) device which does a better job at life safety than Euro-spec RCDs (a compromise necessary due to the larger amount of wiring they protect).

If life safety is a priority e.g. if those 3 circuits serve water-feature loads, you might consider individual branch circuit RCBOs **at 5mA sensitivity**.  This might be in addition to a 30mA RCBO protecting the subpanel supply, which would then protect the range.

I've never heard of a European style (4-continent) wiring setup *not* protecting a range and stove.  Given the dodgy way Europeans do earthing and bonding, I would think at least 30mA protection would be essential.

You did not listen to our standard forum advice and get a really large panel. As such,  you have no spare room for devices of any kind.  If you need RCDs *here*, I think your best bet is to replace the plain circuit breakers with RCBOs. They install with one key difference: the circuit neutral goes to the RCBO and not to the neutral bar. Also a jumper must run from the neutral bar to the RCBO. That is because neutral current must go through the RCBO along with live current, so both can be measured and compared.

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to install a larger panel.
Any additional device like a surge protector or an electronic meter would be easy to add.

And most likely, the cost to replace the 4 breakers with RCBOs, i.e. combined over-current and residual current breakers with same size, would be much more expensive compared to a bigger panel and an additional RCD.

That additional RCD would be a standard 35A type or above, if the breakers no. 2 and 3 and 4 are all on different phases L1, L2, L3.

Would be only visible on a foto which shows the lower connections /connection bars of the breakers.

Another point is the strange connection of Ground (green/yellow) and Neutral (blue) in this panel.

It is most likely not  a main panel, and f.e. if somebody wants or needs to RCD- protect the lines between this small panel and the next upstream panel or anything else which is connected directly to the upstream panel, it wouldn't be possible.

The golden rule is:
Ground and Neutral should be only connected in one and only one central location, which normally is next to the box/panel with the supplier's incoming line.

In other words:
Combined Ground and Neutral lines downstream of an RCD will not work, since current can circumvent the RCD thus imbalancing and tripping it.

Another disadvantage of multiple locations of combined Ground and Neutral lines are ground loops, which can cause noise in acoustic or electronic devices by picking up small voltages by induction, which f.e. can overload amplifier inputs that can be very sensitive to tiny noise levels on the ground line.